# How to create a CBitmap object from the data within a CRect?

Tags: visual-c++, mfc, gdi+, gdi

and anyway how to get the data within a CRect?

Is there any API?

If I can get a corresponding DC, then I can do as following:

```
memDC.CreateCompatibleDC(pRectDC);
memDC.SelectObject(pBm);
memDC.BitBlt(rect.left, rect.top, rect.Width(), rect.Height(), pRectDC, rect.left, rect.top, SRCCOPY);
```

Howerver, I don't known how to get the DC.

Is there someone could help me?

Answer (score 0):

A CRect doesn't have a DC - it's an abstract representation of a rectangle. Use GetDC() on the window you are working with to get a DC.

A CRect doesn't have any data in it yet - it's just a pair of 4 longs that stores the X and Y coordinates of the corners. It's only when you use a CDC's DrawRect() that the data in the CRect is used to set some values on the bitmap of the DC.